# Android: Can not find local variable 'p' when using an array list

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple find unknown game, and I don't want the A.I. to move through a wall the user has made! The walls are in an array list.

Here is the error:

```
Android: Can not find local variable 'p' when using an array list


ArrayList<Point> walls = new ArrayList<Point>();

class Point {
    public Point(int r, int c) {
        row = r;
        col = c;
    }

    public int row;
    public int col;
}
```

This is the method called to see if the ai is at the same co-ordinate.

```
    public boolean unknownThroughWall(int uX, int uY){
    for(Point p: walls){
        if((uX == p.row) && (uY == p.col)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Clean project and run once again. If not resolved, please post the complete log cat.

Comment: Also post in your question where you add your point class to the walls List.